# Run a method once after spring kafka consumer starts

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a consumer in spring boot application, using spring kafka library. I want to set tenancy context per consumer thread i.e. want to call a method on each thread once it is created (just once per thread when created). Currently, I have added it in listner which has @KafkaListner annotation on method, but it calls everytime it polls and does the processing of each record. I want to call this method once when consumer thread is started. Could you please help me here, if we have any such thing.

Comment: Have you tried using a `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`? https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle

Comment: Do you have any example ? I am not sure how we can do that.

Comment: The docs are the example. As shown, `@KafkaListener(id = "myContainer", topics = "...", autoStartup = "false")`, which means you have full control over _when_ the listener actually starts, which you do with a wired `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` instance somewhere else in your app. So, wherever you call your other method, you would also start the listener via that registry. Alternatively, just store a static `AtomicBoolean` in your code that guards the method being called for every kafka record and set it to true once the method is called on the first consumed record

Answer (score 1):

Add an event listener to listen for a consumer started event. It is called on the same thread (by default).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#events

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#event-consumption

Comment: This works thanks a lot